# Why can arrays only be created without `new` during assignment?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, specifications

During assignment of a type `T` array, the `new T[]` portion of the expression is implicit.

```
int[] test = {1,2,3,5};
```

Do the language specifications state why this type of initialization isn't supported elsewhere? Would having a syntax like bellow conflict with any other language rules? Seems like type inference wouldn't be too difficult.

```
public static void test(int[] a, int[] b) { ... };
... 
test({1,2,3}, {4,5,6});
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for the language designers

Comment: Because there is *syntatic sugar* to turn your example into `int[] test = new int[] {1,2,3,5};`

Comment: This is supported by java.lang.String. I believe that this is mostly to do with the complexity of the objects. For simple objects like arrays, the compiler has a fixed representation. For other custom types, the compiler has no way of knowing how to marshall and unmarshall objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JLS does say that you can't do it in section 15. Beginning at [15.12 Method Invocation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) we can see all the valid ways in which you may invoke a method. The important part of that is the optional [*ArgumentList*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ArgumentList) that would give specifications regarding valid syntax for the arguments.

Just below the invocation expressions we can see the definition of [*ArgumentList*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ArgumentList), which is mainly just another link to [*Expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Expression).

When we follow that we can see there are two types of expressions defined in [*Expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Expression); [*LambdaExpression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-LambdaExpression) and [*AssignmentExpression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-AssignmentExpression). As far as I can tell your question is of the ["Class instance creation expressions"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9) type. That is evidented by the fact an invocation such as `foo(new Bar[]{new Bar(), new Bar()});` is valid.

When we follow the link to section 15.9 we can see that what you propose just simply isn't supported.

That doesn't answer why; I do realize that. However, only the person(s) who made that decision can answer the why. We know such craftiness is *possible* as evidenced by other languages.

Comment: Still a little confused, this is a lot of new info! So what definition would make the inline assignment differ from the regular assignment? ie) what makes something like this not possible `String[] a; System.out.println((a = {}));` ?

Comment: @flkes, I believe it's the same reason. You're creating an instance of a class so it still must match the definition I mentioned. The assignment operator could be used like a simple assignment with arrays, but that's not instantiation of a new object. So, given arrays `s` and `t`, this is valid: `foo(s = t);` But that just assigns `t` to `s` and then passes the result into `foo`. Not the same thing.